# How to change the list of items in a Razor DropDownListFor from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a DropDownListFor like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.SelectedStuff, Model.Placeholder, new { id = "targetList", @class = "form-control", style ="width:240px" })
```

Model.Placeholder starts off empty but at some point this function gets called and comes back with a new SelectList that needs to get attached to `targetList` so that it won't be empty anymore.

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: '@Url.Action("GetNewList", "MyModels")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:
    {
        someVal: _someVal
    }
}
).done(
function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $("#labelDirection").text(response.Data.Direction);
    $('#targetList').???????  // want to attach response.Data.StuffForTargetList to targetList
}
```

The function that returns the response looks like this:

```
public ActionResult GetNewList(string someVal)
{
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var stuff = db.SomeTable.Where(t => t.Val > someVal);
    var response = new veiwResponse()
    {
        Direction = "Up",
        StuffForTargetList = stuff.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Selected = false;
            Text = x.Name,
            Value = x.Val
        });
    };

    return Json(response);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to construct the list of options yourself using your data and put it inside the  dropdown.

```
    var options = response.Data.StuffForTargetList.map(function(el, i) {
        return $("<option></option>").val(el.Value).prop("selected", el.Selected).text(el.Text)
    });

    $('#targetList').html(options);
```

Thanks to @GSerg for an improvement of the function.

Comment: Perfect!!  (except for that wayward `_` in the function)

Comment: Generating an HTML tag with string concatenation is the shortest way to invalid HTML and possibly XSS. Please use `$("<option></option>").val(el.Value).prop("selected", el.Selected).text(el.Text)`.

Comment: @GSerg thanks for the heads up on this, function chaining totally popped out of my head :)